# How to calculate a hierarchy level in Dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need some help with a dax measure. Below you see a matrix in Power BI Desktop. What I want is to calculate the ratio of the Sum(of 0 and 1 level) divided by the measure [Total Salg vekt], which I already has calculated. But I am struggling getting the sum of the second level of my product hierarchy. I don't want to calculate level 1 or 3 in the hierarchy.

My hierarchy is located in my Product table and is named like this

Products
  - Category
  - Code
  - SubCategory

Can any of you show a dax code that my work as described above?

Thanks

Regards Geir

[image]

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do. Can you mock up what you want the result to look like?

Comment: I am sorry that I was not clear enough. I want to Sum the second level 281362+180672 and divide it with the total 737357 (sum of all level). The value [Salg vekt kg] is only an ordinary SUM measure. When dragging on a hierarchy I got the values you see on the picture. The question is should I create  a second measure where I set on a spesial filter. Hope I was clear now :-)

Comment: Still not clear. Can you give an example of what you want your matrix to look like with this new measure?

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news:

There's no hierarchy in DAX. 
You'll have to use different filters in order to achieve what you want.

Complete explanation is in here:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/clever-hierarchy-handling-in-dax/

And yes, it is not simple, but it answer your question.